# dplyr filter for shiny error

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

For a crime dataset found in ggmap, I am trying to filter the data frame with offense and/or month combination. Objective is to render data on leaflet map such that if the input selected is robberty and june, it should display only data that meets the criteria.

Here is the code I have:

```
fData <- reactive({
       data <- hustonCrime %>% filter(offense == input$offenseFilter & month == input$monthFilter)
return(data)
})
```

And I am getting these errors when running the app..

```
Warning in Ops.factor(x, 0) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
Warning in Ops.factor(x, 1) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Use the `subset` function. Function reactive is missing from your code.

Comment: Your code seems perfectly fine to me. Are you sure that the problem is not somewhere else? Also, does your `hustonCrime %>% filter(...)` command work properly when run locally (i.e., not within Shiny app)?

Comment: Those are not errors, but warnings. What is the output of `str(hustonCrime)`?

Comment: Am sure the problem is here.

Comment: I never used filter in the shiny example, but when you use factor with filter quotes are needed...filter(month == "June") and you don't....

Comment: Still get the "Warning in Ops.factor(x, 0) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors" and fail to excute...here is the updated code.                                                           if (input$offenseFilter != "All"){
                data <- data %>% filter(offense == "input$offenseFilter") 
                print(data)
                                           }
          if (input$monthFilter != "All"){
                data <- data %>% filter(month == "input$monthFilter") 
                                          }